# AWS Ec2 PowerShell userdata script extremely slow on boot

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

I'm currently starting a "Spot Instance" on the g2.xlarge CPU, and passing a startup script with the userdata paremeter Amazon has made available.

I want to move some files upon startup, from the root volume to the EBS volume. This is all perfect, and I have written a Powershell script to do this which runs just fine when I run the .ps1 file in a Remote Desktop Connected session from my mac. It takes just about 30 seconds to complete moving these files.

However!!! :) When I pass that EXACT SAME PowerShell script into the User-data upon creating the Spot Instance, it looks like it kinda freezes (it doesn't though, it's just slow) and it takes a whopping **10-20 minutes to finish** moving the files! :/

Which means that the whole boot process is taking forever.

I have tried moving the files with robocopy, standard move commands and even the Powershell native Move-Item in a foreach loop. Same applies though: All the commands work just fine when being run from an RDP session, but when passed through the userdata upon launching the instance, to be run at boot, they are extremely slow to finish (or start?) :/

**Does anyone know what the issue could be?**

I really need the server to move the files automatically, and without having to RDP into the server to do it.

Thanks! :)

btw I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2

EDIT:
In case it has something to do with the script I use to move the files, here it is. :)

```
Start-Job -Name MoveFolder -ScriptBlock {
$path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\OldDestination"
$archpath = "Z:\NewDestination"

$counter = 0
$oldpercentage = 0
$files = Get-Childitem -Path $path -recurse -force
$totalcount = $files.count

$lasttime = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -UFormat "%s"))
foreach($file in $files) {
  $filename = $file.FullName
  Move-Item $file.FullName -destination $archpath -force -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
  $counter++
  $percentage = ($counter/$totalcount)*100
  $percentage = [math]::Round($percentage)
  if($percentage -gt 99) { $percentage = 99 }
  $runtime = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -UFormat "%s"))
  $runtime = $runtime - $lasttime

  if($runtime -gt 5) { //Max. log process on server every > 5 seconds
    if($percentage -gt $oldpercentage) {
      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://exampleurl.com/$percentage -Method GET -UseBasicParsing
      $lasttime = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -UFormat "%s"))
      $oldpercentage = $percentage
    }
  }
}
$percentage = 100
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://exampleurl.com/$percentage -Method GET -UseBasicParsing
}
Wait-Job -Name MoveFolder
```

Comment: please be specific when you answer a question. this question has a lots of details. put them in more readable way. that will help you to get the best answer.

Comment: Hi sachith, thanks for the reply. :) However, I don't see how I could be more specific? :)

1) I launch an EC2 Spot Instance on g2.xlarge in Amazon AWS.

2) When launching I pass a Powershell script in <powershell></powershell> tags in the userdata parameter. The script simply moves some files from one volume to another.

Problem: It takes forever to run.

Why do I know it is a problem? Because when running the Powershell script locally after connecting with RDP, it is much faster. So how come? :)

Comment: Are you using a plain vanilla image?  or have you customized it?  If you disable the userdata, how long is the boot time?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) Nope, just a pretty standard windows AMI. The boot time is not impacted by disabling userdata execution. And many scripts seem to work alright in userdata, it's only when I I have a script that moves files (or other larger operations) that boot time worsens a lot.

Hopefully that can help troubleshoot. :)

Comment: Given the nature of the question, this isn't really a PowerShell coding problem. It's more of a question about a performance problem within the AWS cloud platform.